# Unable to commit WebAdministration changes in Azure Web Role

Tags: iis, azure

I have an Azure Web Role running in the new 1.3 SDK and I am having permissions issues when trying to make changes to IIS using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager`.  Whenever I execute `CommitChanges()` it throws this error:

> an UnauthorizedAccessException "Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permissions".

My ServerManager code is executing in the `OnStart` method of the `RoleEntryPoint`.

My understanding was that the purpose of moving to full IIS support in 1.3 was so that we could have greater control over the configuration of our application, including creating new IIS sites on the fly if desired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your role is running with elevated privileges.

Comment: How do you run a role with elevated privileges?  I thought one of the reasons that we have startup tasks was that this wasn't possible?

Comment: Just put <Runtime executionContext="elevated" /> in your ServiceDefinition.csdef

Comment: when I add "<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />" to my web role definition, and attempt to deploy, it fails to start.  I've double checked that I'm doing this correctly.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two questions here.  Firstly the use of IIS in Azure.  Yes using the 1.3 SDK means that we now have access to more features than we did previously.  This means that we can setup more than one site and virtual directories for our sites in the configs as shown in the [training kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_advancedwebandworkerrolesvs2010lab_topic2#_Toc279689491#_Toc279689491).

Secondly there is the privileges issue that you're getting while trying to make changes programatically. I'm going to presume that you're not trying to do one of the things that you can simply do through the config above.  The most likely reason your code is erroring is because web roles are not run with admin privileges.  Fortunately in the 1.3 SDK we also have a way to run code with elevated privileges. As shown elsewhere in the [training kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_advancedwebandworkerrolesvs2010lab_topic3#_Toc279689494#_Toc279689494) you can create a separate .exe that you specify to be run at startup with elevated privileges in the config.

Comment: Well, you can run a startup task elevated, but you can also run the role elevated (code in RoleEntryPoint, such as OnStart). For scripting IIS changes, I believe a startup task is too early (app pool hasn't been set up yet), so it's better to run the role elevated and do the changes in OnStart. Note that running the role elevated doesn't make the actual web app (under IIS) elevated, just the RoleEntryPoint code.

Comment: I was not aware that this was an option, so I've spent some time trying to investigate how to do this.  Despite my best efforts I've been unable to find how to run a role with elevated privileges.  I must be missing an obvious step here, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Providing a clear example for reference to @smarx answer.

Here is the configuration to run `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart` (*`WebRole.Onstart`*) with Admin-level privileges.

```xml
<ServiceDefinition name="MyProject.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="MyProject.WebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated"/> <!-- Required for certain WebRoleOnStart tasks (avoid insufficient permission errors) -->
    <Sites>
       <!-- ... -->
    </Sites>
 </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```